# login authentication in angular

Tags: angular, firebase

I am new to angular and am trying to implement a simple registration and login authentication. I can register easily to push the data to firebase. What I have stuck here is while login if username and password matches then it redirect to another page else redirect throw error.

html:

```
<form id="submission" [formGroup]="fbform">
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" [(ngModel)]="name" formControlName="name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" [(ngModel)]="password" formControlName="password">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" (click)="SignIn(name,password)" class="btn btn-default" [disabled]="!fbform.valid">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

signup-component.ts

```
SignIn(name,password){
  let username = name;
  let password = password;
  let credentials = btoa(username + '??' + btoa(password)) // 

  firebase.database().ref('/users').on('child_added', (data)=>{
      let dat = data.val()
      this.values.push(dat)
      let check = this.values.filter(val => val.name == username && val.name == password );

      //after that am stucked 
      if (check2 ? 'true':'false'){
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/');}
      }
  )
}
```

Comment: why are you not using firebase authentication?. You are reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Use this article to create your auth system using firebase
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start

Comment: i want to login like prashanth@newtt.com

Comment: This is quite dangerous - you shouldn't do it like this. Frontend code can be manipulated which is a huge security issue in this case. Use firebase auth!

Comment: the only way is firebase auth or can i use some other .?

Comment: if am building angular app. i need to choose only firebase auth .?

Comment: Firebase SDK for javascript I think you need.

Comment: Currently you are using Firebase database so I think your credentials are setup you need to add Firebase Auth sdk in your angular app and use it as stated in other answers

Answer (score 3):

You can use firebase authentication

```
 signInUser() {
    this.fire.auth
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.email.value, this.password.value)
      .then(data => {
        this.currentUserUid = JSON.stringify(data.uid);
        sessionStorage.setItem("Sessionuid", this.currentUserUid);
        sessionStorage.setItem("Sessioneml", data.email);

        console.log("Success! You're logged in");

          this.navCtrl.push(HomePage, {
            uid: this.currentUserUid
          });

        // user is logged in
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log("got an error", error);
        this.alert(error.message);
      });

  }
```

Comment: this i can use only gmail think

Comment: gmail is just another way to login

Comment: let me check and let you know

Comment: any success @Prashanth ?

Comment: i have followed [this](https://coursetro.com/posts/code/32/Create-a-Full-Angular-Authentication-System-with-Firebase)

Comment: so finally u have used firebase right?by the way great! Happy Coding

Comment: but again having another problem

Comment: what is it now ?

Comment: i have my company users list and password separately,  how to authenticate with this

Comment: company users list and password separately?? what does it mean?

Answer (score 2):

You have to route back after success.

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('./');
```

or to other Page

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('./LoginDenied');
```

Comment: how to check if success

Comment: I don't try your Example but i Think "check" should have your result if its success.

Answer (score 0):

Use following code:

```
SignIn(name,password){
  let username = name;
  let password = password;
  let credentials = btoa(username + '??' + btoa(password)) // 

  firebase.database().ref('/users').on('child_added', (data)=>{
      let dat = data.val()
      this.values.push(dat)
      let check = this.values.filter(val => val.name == username && val.name == password );

      //after that am stucked 
      if (check && check.length > 0){
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/');}
      } else {
        // you can also use a div to show error. Just create a string
        // varibale and use ngIf to show the error message
        alert("Username or password doesn't match");
      }
  )
}
```

Hope it will help

Comment: even if not matches it redirects only to if case

Comment: put this code console.log(check) after let check = this.values.filter(val => val.name == username && val.name == password );
then let me know what output came on console on your browser

Comment: i have tried only with if username matches its going into if case only

Comment: I just want to see what firebase returns that you are storing in check variable. Just paste here what check variable hold so that I can provide you right solution.

Comment: [console result](https://demo.xerago.com/website/CitiIndia/2017/CMS/Newfolder/doubt-f.png)

Comment: Basically firebase returning an array. I updated answer use that code and it will work fine in your case.

Comment: yep that works as expected, but it check every users in database like am having 8 data in database. first takes undefined and print eight time mismatch then again it executes password matched 8 times [see console](https://demo.xerago.com/website/CitiIndia/2017/CMS/Newfolder/doubt-f.png) why happening like this.?